# Navigate to a lazy component which is a part of lazily loaded submodule in a named secondary/aux outlet

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, router-outlet

There are two modules app and lazy modules. Need do display a lazy component in a named secondary outlet. The 'lazy component' is part of the submodule 'lazy'.

Navigation:

```
 this.router.navigate([{outlets:{primary:'lazy', Secondary:'lazyComponent'}}]);
```

**Correct navigation in answer below**

App Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'lazy',
      loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule'
    }
  ]

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Lazy Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {
          path: 'lazyComponent',
          component: 'lazyComponent'
        }
  ]

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [lazyComponent],
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ]
  })
  export class LazyModule{ }
```

This doesn't work and the error is -> 
Error: **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'lazyComponent'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following router navigation worked.

```
  this.router.navigate(['/', 'lazy', {outlet:{secondary:'lazyComponent'}}])
```

First navigate to app module path and then to secondary outlet of lazy module.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call the path like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/lazy/lazyComponent'])
```